# How to append html tags from an div onto another div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it possible to append html tags from a content-editable div to another div?
I wanted to make an html editor, and I wanted to make automatic preview.

Here is the jsfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/eqw8L4to/12/

And here is the js code where I tried getting html tags from .html, and tried appending it to .result:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".html").keydown(function(event) {
        var x = event.keyCode
        if (x == 27 && event.ctrlKey) {
            $(".result").html("")
            var y = $(".html").html()
            $(".result").append(y)
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/68na2mrq/8/

Get the text from contenteditable div and replace place in the result HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const el = $("div.html");
  const result = $(".result");
  el.keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27 && event.ctrlKey) {
      result.html(el.text());
    }
  })
})
```

[image]

Comment: Your photo shows the editor working, but in the JsFiddle, the editor does not work.

Comment: @WebDevNoob Working gif for you https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgmd3.gif Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. Use the `.html` method to provide the html instead.

Try this snippet and add the following to the test box and you'll see it is working.

```html
<div class='rendered'>blue text</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".html").keydown(function(event) {
        var x = event.keyCode
        if (x == 27 && event.ctrlKey) {
            $(".result").html("")
            var y = $(".html").text()
            $(".result").html(y)
        }
    })
})
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
}

.html{
    color: white;
    height:50vh;
    width:100vw;
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
}

.result{
    height:50vh;
    width:100vw;
    background-color:#f5ff5;
}

.rendered {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="html" contenteditable="true">
    
</div>

<div class="result">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to know which element your editor are using, but if `div.html` is the element that you want to get the text to preview, you just gotta remove double quotes and you'll get the content of element.

Thy this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".html").keydown(function(event) {
        var x = event.keyCode;
        if (x == 27 && event.ctrlKey) {
            $(".result").html();
            var y = $(".html").html();
            $(".result").append(y);
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, as you’ve mentioned that you need an HTML editor with automatic preview, I tried it by reading the contenteditable div’s input as text and then convert it to HTML using `object.src = "data:text/html"` with a default charset: UTF-8, and show it as the src of an iframe on keyup.

I’ve read your code, but I am not very well-versed in JQuery...

So, in standard the JavaScript it would be something like this:

```
const editor = document.querySelector(".editable-div");
const result = document.querySelector("iframe");

editor.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  var html = editor.textContent;
  iframe.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(html);
```

Here’s an example snippet:

```js
const editor = document.querySelector(".editor");
const result = document.querySelector("iframe");

editor.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  var html = editor.textContent;
  result.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(html);
});

/*a paste function just as extra info*/
 
editor.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
        document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
    });
```

```css
/* all CSS is for demo snippet */

.editor {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80vw;
  color: white;
  font: monospace;
  overflow-y: auto;
  white-space: pre;
  outline: none;
}

.result {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 80vw;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor" contenteditable>WriteCode</div>
<iframe class="result"></iframe>
```

Here’s an image of it working:
[image: Image of the editor working]

---

Hope I could help.

Comment: I do know the disadvantages of making it like so (no vh; no position fixed; etc). I will just append it to the iframe so that there can be a body tag, etc.

Comment: @AvinavChalise the css was just for a demo snippet, still I’ve changed it... is it fine now?

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted it. I really like the code, just that I actually wanted to try to do it via appending it or changing the innerHtml.

Comment: @AvinavChalise that’s not what I intended to say, sorry if you felt bad, no hard feelings

Comment: Well, innerHTML can do it, but only with a little more of JavaScript, cause divs or spans don’t have an src value and will print the ‘data:text/html...’ line..